# Can't remove-item because it is in use, although it isn't

Tags: powershell

I have a script that creates a working folder, moves some stuff in, makes some changes and then moves the output and then deletes the working folder. I cannot for the life of me get this folder to remove properly.

Originally it was due a PDF tied up because I was manipulating it with pdftk, however after properly using .Dispose() it still gives me an error saying it's in use. I can manually delete it by right clicking, but if I try to use "remove-item $folder -recurse" it gives me the error. I've even tried using start-sleep to delay the action, but it does not make a difference.

Is there anything I'm not thinking of? I tried remove-variable after dispose, but it threw an error.

Here are some relevent snippets of my code:

```
$submitdir = "D:\SUBFTP\SUBMIT"
$local = "$submitdir\${filename}_dir"

#...

$reader = New-Object iTextSharp.text.pdf.pdfreader -ArgumentList $pdf

  $global:outvar = ""
  for ($page = 1; $page -le $reader.NumberOfPages; $page++) {
   $lines = [char[]]$reader.GetPageContent($page) -join "" -split "`n"
   $global:outvar = $global:outvar += ("`n" + $lines) 
   if(($page % 50) -eq 0) {
     #echo "$file - parsing page $page";
     LogWrite "$file - parsing page $page" }
  }

#... end of script below...

$reader.Dispose()
start-sleep 20; 
rm $local -recurse
```

Comment: Does adding the -Force switch help?  You can also try the -WhatIf switch to see if you can get a print out of what might be attempted.

Comment: What error did `Remove-Variable` throw? That could very likely be relevant.

Comment: Error that     Remove-Variable gives is "Cannot find a variable with the name 'iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader'

Comment: @fudge isn't the variable called `$reader`?

Comment: @fudge you are getting that error because you need to pass the variable name without the `$`: `Remove-Variable -Name reader -Force`.  Otherwise, Powershell resolves it to its value and uses that as the variable name.  Also, can you check with [ProcessExplorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) to see if there are open handles to the file?

Comment: Same problem here. I create a folder and use `wget` and `openssl` to populate it. When I am done, I cannot freaking delete it! Anyone got this to work?